# All of my ids increment when i try to add one id

Tags: java, arraylist, jlist

I am trying to add a patient id when a patient is created, the id's will increment by one every time. But when run my code it increments the ids of all the other ids as well.

```
    JButton btnCp = new JButton("Create Patient");
    btnCp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//add action listener to btnCp (Create Patient Button)
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            name = pateintNameTextField.getText();//reads entered text
            address = patientAddressTextField.getText();
            phone = patientPhoneTextField.getText();

            pateintNameTextField.setText("");//sets fields back to empty ("")
            patientAddressTextField.setText("");
            patientPhoneTextField.setText("");




                Patient.setID(Patient.patientNum +1);


            Patient patient = new Patient(name,address,phone);//adds the Patient to the patient class
            patientListModel.addElement(patient);//adds patient to patientLst
            Patient.aPatientList.add(patient);
```

My Patient class is as follows:

```
public class Patient implements Serializable{

public static int patientNum;
public String patientName;
public String patientAddress;
public String patientPhone;


public static ArrayList<Patient> aPatientList = new ArrayList<Patient>();



public Patient(String n, String a, String p){


    patientName = n;
    patientAddress = a;
    patientPhone = p;


}

public static void setID(int id){

    patientNum = id;



}

public static int getID(){

    return patientNum;

}


public void setName(String n){

    patientName = n;



}

public String getName(){

    return patientName;

}

public void setAddress(String a){

    patientAddress = a;


}

public String getAddress(){

    return patientAddress;
}



public void SetPhoneNum(String p){
    patientPhone = p;

}

public String getPhoneNum(){

    return patientPhone;
}

public String toString() {
    return "ID: " +getID() + " Name: "+ getName() +" Address: "+getAddress() +" Phone Number: "+getPhoneNum();
  }




}
```

Also im then writing the patients to a jList. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have declared `patientNum` as `static`, all the `patientNum` will increment if you increment even one of them, since it is shared by the objects.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `patientNum` to be `static`, [which means that all instances of `Patient` share the same value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). Remove the `static` modifier so that each instance gets its own `patientNum`. Likewise, you'll need to make `getID()` and `setID()` non-static.

At this point you'll want to introduce a static *counter* used exclusively for getting the next patient ID.

```
public class Patient {

    private static int patientIdCounter = 0;

    private int patientNum;
    // snip

    public Patient(String n, String a, String p){
        patientId = patientIdCounter++;
        patientName = n;
        patientAddress = a;
        patientPhone = p;
    }

    public int getID() {
      return patientNum;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Patient patient = new Patient(name,address,phone);
```

(removed unrelated fields & methods for brevity)

Comment: but then if they are not static how do i increment them?

Comment: @SeanO'Riordan: You need to increment the number for a *specific* patient. Do you understand the difference between static and non-static variables/methods?

Comment: @SeanO'Riordan, read the Java Tutorial linked in my answer if you haven't already. That should illuminate things.

Answer (score 1):

because you Id is set with the value of patientNum which is a static value of the single object and the same reference is passed on to all Patient Objects.

You need to create another private int Id and you need set its value while initializing the object.

```
public Patient(String n, String a, String p){


    patientName = n;
    patientAddress = a;
    patientPhone = p;
    id = patientNum ++;

}
```

also remove setId method

Comment: remove the setId method from the Patient class? as well as the SOR class?

Comment: @SeanO'Riordan yes obviously. since Id is only supposed to be an incremental value

Answer (score 1):

You have declared Integer `patientNum` in your Patient Class as static, so when you increment it, all the instances of patient will share that value and their patientNum variable will be seen as incremented . . .

Answer (score 0):

`patientNum` is declared as `static` that's why it is behaving this way.

The easiest way to look at this is that `static` members of a class are "class-level" members, therefore all instances of the class share them. non-`static` members are on the other hand, are instance-level members.